# How to install 19c with ansible-oracle playbook?

Tags: oracle, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible-oracle playbook (https://github.com/oravirt/ansible-oracle) to install a 19c database, however, seems it always create default 18c, i cannot find which file to edit or which param/option to feed into CLI command below,

ansible-playbook single-instance-db-on-fs.yml -e hostgroup=myhostgroup

who can give me some hint, thanks.

Thanks & Regards,
Martin.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ansible 19.3 was included but entries for 19.3 missing in `ansible-oracle/roles/orasw-meta/defaults/main.yml` (db_homes_config and db_homes_installed)

Comment: Also check `ansible-oracle/group_vars/vbox-si-fs/databases.yml `

Comment: Thanks Suresh for the helpful hint, i eventually succeeded the 19c install with some fixing on below files,ansible-oracle/roles/orasw-meta/defaults/main.yml
ansible-oracle/group_vars/vbox-si-fs/databases.yml
ansible-oracle/roles/oradb-manage-db/defaults/main.yml
ansible-oracle/roles/oradb-manage-db/templates/netca.rsp.19.3.0.0.j2

Comment: Glad it worked out.Curious response file exists `..templeates/netsca.rsp.193.0.0.j2` what's wrong with that file?

Comment: Figured out that file has no  parameters :-)

Comment: that netsca.rsp.193.0.0.j2 is missing, so i just make one by copying from 18c, it works :)